# Convert NSArray to NSString in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring, nsarray

I am wondering how to convert an **NSArray** `[@"Apple", @"Pear ", 323, @"Orange"]` to a string in **Objective-C**.

Comment: [Convert NSString separated by comma to NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8204215/194544)

Comment: @beryllium That question was asked two *years* after my question.

Answer (score 544, accepted):

```
NSString * result = [[array valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: Won't this accomplish the same thing as calling [array description]?

Comment: @TechZen - no, because `[array description]` inserts newlines and the outer parentheses.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer!

Comment: Awesome. The name valueForKey does not make its purpose obvious.

Comment: Just want to be sure here, but is `NSString * myString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];` an acceptable substitute for this?

Comment: @0x7fffffff: It's equivalent if the array contains only "basic" types. For complex types, it will stringify them as `<ClassName: InstanceAddress>`. The `valueForKey` makes it retrieve the specified property for each item. In this case, `description` is a `NSString *` property from `NSObject`, whose getter can be overriden by its subclasses.

Answer (score 32):

One approach would be to iterate over the array, calling the `description` message on each item:

```
NSMutableString * result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSObject * obj in array)
{
    [result appendString:[obj description]];
}
NSLog(@"The concatenated string is %@", result);
```

Another approach would be to do something based on each item's class:

```
NSMutableString * result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSObject * obj in array)
{
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        // append something
    }
    else
    {
        [result appendString:[obj description]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"The concatenated string is %@", result);
```

If you want commas and other extraneous information, you can just do:

```
NSString * result = [array description];
```

Comment: If the array has many elements it might be more efficient to first convert all elements to strings (probably using `-description`) and concat them after that using `-componentsJoinedByString:` with `@""` as the parameter.

Comment: I would go with this method over the one by Dave Delong unless your just debugging.

Answer (score 18):

I think Sanjay's answer was almost there but i used it this way

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hello",@"World", nil];
NSString *greeting = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@",greeting);
```

Output :

```
2015-01-25 08:47:14.830 StringTest[11639:394302] Hello World
```

As Sanjay had hinted - I used method *componentsJoinedByString* from NSArray that does joining and gives you back **NSString**

BTW **NSString** has reverse method *componentsSeparatedByString* that does the splitting and gives you **NSArray** back .

Answer (score 10):

I recently found a really good tutorial on Objective-C Strings:

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c-strings-a-guide-for-beginners/

And I thought that this might be of interest:

If you want to split the string into an array use a method called componentsSeparatedByString to achieve this:

```
NSString *yourString = @"This is a test string";
    NSArray *yourWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    // yourWords is now: [@"This", @"is", @"a", @"test", @"string"]
```

if you need to split on a set of several different characters, use NSString’s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:

```
NSString *yourString = @"Foo-bar/iOS-Blog";
NSArray *yourWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                  [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-/"]
                ];

// yourWords is now: [@"Foo", @"bar", @"iOS", @"Blog"]
```

Note however that the separator string can’t be blank. If you need to separate a string into its individual characters, just loop through the length of the string and convert each char into a new string:

```
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[myString length]];
for (int i=0; i < [myString length]; i++) {
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [myString characterAtIndex:i]];
    [characters addObject:ichar];
}
```

Comment: This is in no way answering the question, is it?

Answer (score 9):

```
NSString * str = [componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

and you have dic or multiple array then used bellow

```
NSString * result = [[array valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three", nil];
NSString *stringFromArray = [array componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

The first line initializes an array with objects.
The second line joins all elements of that array by adding the string inside the "" and returns a string.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, sincerely!

Answer (score 2):

**Objective C Solution**

```
NSArray * array = @[@"1", @"2", @"3"];
NSString * stringFromArray = [[array valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@"-"];   // "1-2-3"
```

Those who are looking for a solution in `Swift`

If the array contains strings, you can use the String's join method:

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]

let stringFromArray = "-".join(array) // "1-2-3"
```

**In Swift 2:**

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]

let stringFromArray = array.joinWithSeparator("-") // "1-2-3"
```

**In Swift 3 & 4**

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]

let stringFromArray = array.joined(separator: "-") // "1-2-3"
```

Comment: The first section (Objective-C) does not add any value to the almost decade old accepted answer. The other sections do not answer the question, which is explicitly about Objective-C.

Answer (score -2):

The way I know is easy.

```
var NSArray_variable = NSArray_Object[n]
var stringVarible = NSArray_variable as String
```

`n` is the inner position in the array
This in SWIFT Language. 
It might work in **Objective C**

Answer (score -2):

Swift 3.0 solution:

```
let string = array.joined(separator: " ")
```