# How to convert NSArray into NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

How to convert NSArray into NSString in objective-c?

Comment: Could you be more specific? An NSArray can contain instances of any Objective-C class.

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828665/convert-nsarray-to-nsstring-objective-c

Comment: [Convert NSString separated by comma to NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8204215/194544)

Comment: Well, if you're not too particular you can always use `description`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Bearing in mind that you don't say what's in the NSArray, you can do this:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"foo", @"bar", @"baz"];
[arr componentsJoinedByString: @","]
```

Comment: Yes, I find that this is strongly assuming that you are having text. Or is it using description field instead? Most likely... But barely usable in that context.

Answer (score 12):

Aternatively to Frank's method, which works pretty well, you could also do

```
NSString *myArrayString = [array description];
```

The default implementation of description on NSArray will print out the contents in a neatly formatted fashion.

Comment: one problem here is that myArrayString will have {} around the text...how to get rid of this? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is how I have converted my `NSArray` to `NSString`

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:aArray options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This is the safest method I've found assuming you eventually want to get back to an array state. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 latest updates

`let string = array.componentsJoined(by: ",")`

you can used any separator in function which you want to separate the array elements currently in above example is ",".