# Remove brackets and quotes when displaying in textfield after using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I would like to remove the brackets and quotes when it displays in textfield. I am using NSPredicate to get the contents that I want.

Here is my code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Block == '1234'"];
NSArray *predicateArray = [blockStage filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
predicateStreetName = [predicateArray valueForKey:@"Street Name"];
streetName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", predicateStreetName];
```

Here is how it displays in the textfield:

```
(
    "Street Name Value"
)
```

This code displays the street name value that I want, but however, it displays with the brackets and quotes. How do I remove them?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this [Convert NSArray to NSString in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1828665/868703) 
this answer [Convert NSArray to NSString in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828665/convert-nsarray-to-nsstring-in-objective-c/1828711#1828711), the ' componentsJoinedByString:@"" ' will help solve your problem. Do it here:

streetName.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", predicateStreetName] **componentsJoinedByString:@""**];

kuddos,
aimzy :)