# How to write proper description method to a class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, methods

How to write proper description method to a class?

I have implemented

```
- (NSString *)description {
     NSString *descriptionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@ \n Address: %@ \n", self.name, self.address];
     return descriptionString;

}
```

Evrey thing is fine if I call description on my object. But if I have an array of objects and I call description on it I get:

> "Name: Alex \n Address: some address \n",

What I would like to get is

> "Name: Alex
>
> Address: some address"

Comment: you will have to loop over the elements and call `description` on each. Array description is formatted output, which may short-circuit some things like "\n", to keep formatting consistent

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1828689/971401](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1828689/971401). Answers there can probably help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I dig a little more in iOS frameworks and I have observed that the default behavior of the iOS sdk description is not to place "\n" but ";".

Example:

```
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    NSLog(@"FontDescription:%@",[font description]);

    NSMutableArray *fontsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        [fontsArray addObject:font];
    }
    NSLog(@"FontsArrayDescription:%@",[fontsArray description]);
```

The out put is:

> FontDescription: font-family: "Helvetica"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px
>
> FontsArrayDescription:(
>
> ```
>  "<UICFFont: 0x6e2d8b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px",
>  "<UICFFont: 0x6e2d8b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px",
>  "<UICFFont: 0x6e2d8b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px",
>  "<UICFFont: 0x6e2d8b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px",
>  "<UICFFont: 0x6e2d8b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px",    
>  "<UICFFont: 0x6e2d8b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px",
>  "<UICFFont: 0x6e2d8b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px",
>  "<UICFFont: 0x6e2d8b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px",
>  "<UICFFont: 0x6e2d8b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px",
>  "<UICFFont: 0x6e2d8b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px"
> ```
>
> )

So I have decided to use the same approach with my class.

```
- (NSString *)description {
     NSString *descriptionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@; Address: %@;", self.name, self.address];
     return descriptionString;

}
```

And the out put will be:

> "Name: Alex; Address: some address;"

For object it self.

> objecsArrayDescription:(
>
> ```
>  "Name:Alex; Address: some address;",
>  "Name:Alex; Address: some address;",
>  "Name:Alex; Address: some address;",
>  "Name:Alex; Address: some address;",
>  "Name:Alex; Address: some address;",
>  "Name:Alex; Address: some address;",
>  "Name:Alex; Address: some address;",
>  "Name:Alex; Address: some address;",
>  "Name:Alex; Address: some address;",
>  "Name:Alex; Address: some address;"
> ```
>
> )

For an array of objects.

Answer (score 19):

Additionally you can use a carriage return `\r` which will end up in a new line too (even in a NSArray description)

Comment: Excellent answer! Although I still can't get \t to work, so I ended up with "    " (4 spaces).

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks